# Prove that $(0, 1)$ is open if we call $U$ in $\mathbb R$ open if $\forall x\in U\ \exists \epsilon>0, (x - \epsilon , x + \epsilon) \subseteq U$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Hey guys I am new to discrete math and as an exercise I am supposed to prove that $(0,1)$ is an open set by considering the a subset $U\subseteq \mathbb R$ open if

$$\forall x\in U\ \exists \epsilon>0, (x - \epsilon , x + \epsilon) \subseteq U.$$

My textbooks suggests that answer requires setting $\epsilon$ to $\min\{t, t-1\}$ which really doesnt make any sense to me, any help on this would be great! Thank you! Sorry if my $\LaTeX$ is off, I am using a computer that does not display it on the screen before you post the question

Comment: What's $t$?It's related to $x$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $t\in(0,1)$, so $0<t<1$. Then the choice $\epsilon=\min\{t,1-t\}$ first of all guarantees that $\epsilon>0$ (because $t>0$ and $1-t>1-1=0$) as required. Moreover, $t-\epsilon\ge 0$ because $\epsilon\le t$ and $t+\epsilon\le 1$ because $\epsilon\le 1-t$ (recall that $\min\{u,v\}$ is $\le u$ and $\le v$). So the interval $(t-\epsilon,t+\epsilon)$ has its left end $\ge 0$ and its right end $\le 1$, which means that $(t-\epsilon,t+\epsilon)\subseteq (0,1)$.

Comment: thank you! This makes a lot more sense

Comment: Shouldn't we set =min{/2,(1−)/2}. For instance, if we consider t = 0.5 then  = 0.5, that would give us an epsilon ball that would touch (Include) 0 and 1, but we have to show epsilon ball around any point has to be in (0,1), so it can't touch 0 and 1?

Answer (score 0):

So we are after proving $(0,1)$ is open. Let $x \in (0,1)$, fix $\epsilon = \min\{x, 1-x\}$ and see if the definition fits...